# How to prove statement with quantifiers and 2 different number sets?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-writing, quantifiers

How would I prove something like this:

$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \exists n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $|x − n| < \frac{1}{4}$

I read it as "For all real numbers $x$, there exists an integer $n$, such that the absolute value of $x-n$ is less than $\frac{1}{4}$."

Is this correct?

I understand this is such an easy proof and I assume it is obviously true, but I don't really understand where to start it or how to prove it. Should I do it by cases? Should I do it by contradiction?

Comment: If $x=0.5$, what value of $n$ would you choose?

Comment: Another way to interpret it is "For any real number, there is some integer with distance less than $\frac{1}{4}$ from it". Maybe this helps with trying to prove the statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't! That statement is wrong. If $x=1.5$, there are no integers that are within a quarter of $x$!

Comment: So, basically I must "prove this is wrong" using this as a disproof?

Comment: Yes. We say in math that $x=1.5$ is a **counterexample** to your statement.

Comment: Also important to note is if $x = 0.5n \pm .25$ this is not true for any integer $n$.

Comment: Well, is 0 considered an integer?

Comment: @Mitchell yes. It is an integer.